# Uniqueness of solution for a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, pseudoinverse

> Suppose that $A\vec{x} = \vec{0}$ is a linear system. Also columns of
>   $A$ are linearly independent. Prove that $\vec{x} = \vec{0}$ is the
>   solution and it's unique.

**My answer:** If $A$ is a square matrix, then it has a inverse because of independent columns. So $A\vec{x} = \vec{0}$ implies that $A^{-1}A\vec{x} = A^{-1}\vec{0} = \vec{0}$ and then $\vec{x} = \vec{0}$.

If $A$ is not a square matrix, it has a left inverse because of independent columns. So $A\vec{x} = \vec{0}$ implies that $A^{-1}A\vec{x} = A^{-1}\vec{0} = \vec{0}$ and then $\vec{x} = \vec{0}$. Here $A^{-1}$ denotes the left inverse.

My professor said that second part of my argument isn't complete and it only shows that $\vec{x} = \vec{0}$ is a solution and uniqueness hasn't been proved yet. I don't get that. Is that true?

Comment: You would want to show that $A^{-1}$ is also full rank, if not when you multiply the equation by $A^{-1}$ you may remove some solution due to the fact that the transformation is not injective.

Comment: @P.Quinton Could you explain more, please?

Comment: @Jethro So how we can use left inverse?

Comment: @S.H.W Ignore my previous comment. Actually I think your proof is correct. $A^{-1}A x=x$ is correct.

Comment: @S.H.W But it can be argued more simply: just apply the *definition* of linear independence.